# Summoner Unchained and full Eidolon HP

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, unchained

I was reading the [Summoner Unchained](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained) class and feel confused by how the eidolon "heals"

> A summoner can summon his eidolon in a ritual that takes 1 minute to perform. When summoned in this way, the eidolon's hit points are unchanged from the last time it was summoned. The only exception to this is if the eidolon was slain, in which case it returns with half its normal hit points. The eidolon does not heal naturally.

From the way I read this:

- Eidolons never recover any HP from resting
- Eidolons do not regain HP when summoned or unsummoned unless they were killed
- Eidolons are resummoned with whatever HP they had remaining (provided it wasnt killed)

So my question is, is the only way to have it with full HP be the very first time its summoned or have it healed with magic?